# Pre-install Jenkins plugins using Docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

If I have a jenkins docker image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

is there a way to pre-install certain plugins using the Docker image, for example all the bitbucket plugins:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I assume we'd probably have to unpack some tars to the filesystem somewhere like so:

```
 FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

 USER root

 WORKDIR /jenkins/main/dir

 RUN tar -xvf some-jenkins-plugins.tar
```

Comment: Are you looking to install them locally, over the web, or from either?

Comment: Either way, preferably through the web tho

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the right idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328278/installing-jenkins-plugins-to-docker-jenkins/29328489#29328489

so in the Dockerfile you'd just use:

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: You can also have the plugins in the RUN command, separated by spaces: `RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh plugin-1 plugin-2 plugin-N`